# Create indexable, human-readable URLs from GET-requests in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a database and my goal is to use it to generate pages that can be indexed by a search engine as well as URLs that are nice and human-readable.

What I've got is something similar to this.

1. An array of data from a Database, with which I generate a tags using a foreach loop.
2. The href redirects and puts the persons name in a GET-parameter.
3. The GET parameter is then used to populate the h1 tag as well as the title tag and other elements on the page.

```
<?php
    $indexable = array(
        "Barack Obama",
        "Donald Trump",
        "Bill Clinton"
    )
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?php echo($_GET['person'])?>s Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello <?php echo($_GET['person'])?></h1>
    <?php
        foreach($indexable as $i)
        {
            echo('<a href="indexable.php?person='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>');
            echo('<br>');
        }
    ?>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**First question**

The resulting URL lookes like this:

```
website.com/?person=Barack%20Obama
```

What I want is something like this

```
website.com/Barack_Obama
```

**Second question**

I'm completely new to SEO so bear with me if my question doesn't make sense or is unclear.
But, I eventually what the resulting "pages", in this case Barack Obama, Donald Trump, Bill Clinton to be indexable by Google so that users can find them. Is this possible or do I have to create one HTML page per person?

Comment: Use `-` instead of `_`. You can use simple `str_replace`. Plus rewrite in .htaccess of course.

Comment: Ok, so str replace in the a tag to replace " " with "_" and then str replace again to get the space back to display a proper h1 and title?
echo('<a href="indexable.php?person='.str_replace(" ","_",$p).'">'.$p.'</a>');

Comment: I didn't know I could achieve this in .htaccess. Do you mind sharing what settings to use or point me to a resource?

Answer (score 1):

Replace spaces with `_`:

```php
echo('<a href="indexable.php?person='.str_replace(" ", "_", $i).'">'.$i.'</a>');
```

For using `website.com/Barack_Obama` instead `website.com/?person=Barack_Obama` you have at least two options:

1. Using `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /indexable.php?person=$1 [NC]
```

2. Using `parse_url` function in php

Check document of `parse_url` function [Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

> This function parses a URL and returns an associative array containing any of the various components of the URL that are present. The values of the array elements are not URL decoded.